# Deaf Grandma Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am going through the Chris Pine Ruby tutorial. In one of the exercises, I have to extend the program by making the user write "BYE" three times in a row to shut the program. I wanted to take it a step further and have Grandma respond on the third "BYE" before the program shuts down. Every time I type "BYE" i get two error messages, but the program still runs like it should aside from that. The error messages are:

```
DeafGrandma.rb:11: warning: already initialized constant BYE
DeafGrandma.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BYE was here
```

Here is my code:

```
# DeafGrandma

  BYE = 0

    while BYE < 3

        puts "What do you want to say to Grandma?"
        tell_grandma = gets.chomp

        if tell_grandma == "BYE"
            BYE += 1
        end

        if tell_grandma != tell_grandma.upcase
            puts "HUH!? SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
        else
            puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{1929 + rand(22)}!"
        end  
    end 

    while BYE = 3
        puts "BYE BYE, SONNY!"
        break
    end
```

What must I change to get rid of these errors? Thank you in advance.

Comment: FWIW: `BYE = 3` is assigning instead of comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants start with capital letters and are just like variables, with the only exception that constants are meant to remain constant and not change throughout your program. In this case you're changing it by adding `+=1` every time you mention 'BYE'.

Constants can not be reinitialized generally speaking, to fix your problem and get rid of the errors you need to change all references from `BYE` to `bye`

```
bye = 0

while bye < 3

    puts "What do you want to say to Grandma?"
    tell_grandma = gets.chomp

    if tell_grandma == "BYE"
        bye += 1
    end

    if tell_grandma != tell_grandma.upcase
        puts "HUH!? SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
    else
        puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{1929 + rand(22)}!"
    end  
end 

while bye = 3
    puts "BYE BYE, SONNY!"
    break
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer given by Nabeel Amjad, a variable whose name begins with a capital letter is a 'constant' in Ruby. Of course, Ruby being Ruby, it's still possible to reassign these so-called 'constants' (because Ruby is flexible that way), but you get a warning, because that's not what constants are actually *for*, and in most cases when you reassign a constant it's a mistake.

You can fix it by simply renaming the variable `BYE` to `bye` (or `bYE` or `the_number_of_times_the_user_said_bye`)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did when doing Chris' Pine exercises:

```
       puts "Start talking to Grandma. Sometimes she can't hear, so you might need to SPEAK UP! To leave just shout 'Bye'"
talk = gets.chomp
while talk != "BYE"
    if talk == talk.downcase || talk == talk.capitalize
        puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
        talk = gets.chomp
    elsif talk == talk.upcase
        puts "NO, NOT SINCE" + " " + (1900 + rand(81)).to_s + "!"
        talk = gets.chomp
    elsif talk == "BYE"
        break
    end
end
```

Hope this helps! I had so much fun with this...Love Chris Pine's Learn to Program

Comment: This also contemplates the case .capitalize